# eigenvalue of Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Questions about rank and eigenvalues of a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257994/questions-about-rank-and-eigenvalues-of-a-matrix)

Let
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&w&w^2\\w&w^2&1\\w^2&w&1\end{pmatrix}$$
Where $w$ is a complex no. s.t. $w^3=1$.
Its clear by adding columns of matrix that $0$ is an eigen value of $A$.

Do there exist linearly independent vectors $u,v\in\mathbb{C}^3$ s.t. $Au=Av=0$?

can anyone help me please....

Comment: You may learn how to type mathematical formulae [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It is a basic etiquette to format your question in a readable form.

Comment: Also, if you read a post and want to see how a mathematical expression in it was typed, you may right-click on it and choose "Show Math As > TeX Commands" from the context menu.

Comment: So you want to find the rank of A? What do eigenvalues have to do with it?

Comment: I want to find if  there exist linearly independent vectors u,v∈C3 s.t. Au=Av=0?

Answer (score 2):

You just want to what is the rank of $A$. Notice that the second and third column are just the first column scaled by $w$ and $w^2$ respectively. Thus, the rank is at most $1$ (so it's precisely $1$, since $A$ is not the zero matrix).
In other words, the dimension of the kernel of $A$ is $2$, i.e. there are two linearly independent vectors $u,v$ with $Au = Av = 0$. You can even find them explicitly: one is $(1,1,1)$, another is $(1,w,w^2)$ (other choices are of course possible).

Comment: rank of A is 2 not 1

Comment: third column aren't the first column scaled by  w2 so rank of A is 2 not

Comment: third column aren't the first column scaled by w2 so rank of A is 2 not 1

Comment: @prakash: are you sure? to me it looks as if $w^2 \cdot (1,w,w^2) = (w^2,w^3,w^4) = (w^2,1,w)$.

Comment: @Feanor My fault: when I TeX-ified the OP's question, I wrongly typed the last row of the matrix as $(w^2,1,w)$. It should be $(w^2,w,1)$.